# error[E0597]: borrowed value does not live long enough when trying to return &'static

Tags: rust

I'm trying to rewrite the `publicsuffix` crate, hoping to get better performance. I'm using the Python library with the same name as a reference and after simplifying its data structures, I came up with this:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Node<T> {
    pub name: T,
    pub children: Vec<Node<T>>,
}
```

I was feeling too lazy to implement structure loading before I get a signal that it works well, which is why I decided to hardcode it. I keep getting `error[E0015]: calls in statics are limited to constant functions, struct and enum constructors` when I tried to do something like `pub static root = Node { name: "x", children: vec![]};`, so I decided to wrap it in a function. I ended up with [this file](https://gitlab.com/d33tah/psl-rewrite/blob/master/src/lib.rs), which takes forever to build (about 10 minutes). After asking on IRC #rust-beginners, I got a suggestion to try using references to array slices instead and ended up with this sample code:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Node<T: 'static> {
    pub name: T,
    pub children: &'static [Node<T>],
}
pub fn return_root() -> Node<&'static str> {
    return Node {
        name: "root",
        children: &[Node {
            name: "uk",
            children: &[
                Node {
                    name: "ac",
                    children: &[][..],
                },
                Node {
                    name: "co",
                    children: &[
                        Node {
                            name: "blogspot",
                            children: &[][..],
                        },
                        Node {
                            name: "no-ip",
                            children: &[][..],
                        },
                    ][..],
                },
                Node {
                    name: "gov",
                    children: &[Node {
                        name: "service",
                        children: &[][..],
                    }][..],
                },
                Node {
                    name: "ltd",
                    children: &[][..],
                },
                Node {
                    name: "me",
                    children: &[][..],
                },
                Node {
                    name: "net",
                    children: &[][..],
                },
                Node {
                    name: "nhs",
                    children: &[][..],
                },
                Node {
                    name: "org",
                    children: &[][..],
                },
                Node {
                    name: "plc",
                    children: &[][..],
                },
                Node {
                    name: "police",
                    children: &[][..],
                },
                Node {
                    name: "sch",
                    children: &[Node {
                        name: "*",
                        children: &[][..],
                    }][..],
                },
            ][..],
        }][..],
    };
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=94cc36d8a85a29e1559119fd07b2d096&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015)

This does not compile and I don't understand the error messages:

```
error[E0597]: borrowed value does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:9:20
   |
9  |           children: &[Node {
   |  ____________________^
10 | |             name: "uk",
11 | |             children: &[
12 | |                 Node {
...  |
71 | |             ][..],
72 | |         }][..],
   | |__________^ temporary value does not live long enough
73 |       };
   |        - temporary value only lives until here
   |
   = note: borrowed value must be valid for the static lifetime...
   = note: consider using a `let` binding to increase its lifetime

error[E0597]: borrowed value does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:11:24
   |
11 |               children: &[
   |  ________________________^
12 | |                 Node {
13 | |                     name: "ac",
14 | |                     children: &[][..],
...  |
70 | |                 },
71 | |             ][..],
   | |_____________^ temporary value does not live long enough
72 |           }][..],
73 |       };
   |        - temporary value only lives until here
   |
   = note: borrowed value must be valid for the static lifetime...
   = note: consider using a `let` binding to increase its lifetime

error[E0597]: borrowed value does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:18:32
   |
18 |                       children: &[
   |  ________________________________^
19 | |                         Node {
20 | |                             name: "blogspot",
21 | |                             children: &[][..],
...  |
26 | |                         },
27 | |                     ][..],
   | |_____________________^ temporary value does not live long enough
...
73 |       };
   |        - temporary value only lives until here
   |
   = note: borrowed value must be valid for the static lifetime...
   = note: consider using a `let` binding to increase its lifetime

error[E0597]: borrowed value does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:31:32
   |
31 |                       children: &[Node {
   |  ________________________________^
32 | |                         name: "service",
33 | |                         children: &[][..],
34 | |                     }][..],
   | |______________________^ temporary value does not live long enough
...
73 |       };
   |        - temporary value only lives until here
   |
   = note: borrowed value must be valid for the static lifetime...
   = note: consider using a `let` binding to increase its lifetime

error[E0597]: borrowed value does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:66:32
   |
66 |                       children: &[Node {
   |  ________________________________^
67 | |                         name: "*",
68 | |                         children: &[][..],
69 | |                     }][..],
   | |______________________^ temporary value does not live long enough
...
73 |       };
   |        - temporary value only lives until here
   |
   = note: borrowed value must be valid for the static lifetime...
   = note: consider using a `let` binding to increase its lifetime
```

Is there a way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you are creating a slice, you reference it again with `&[][..]`. This creates a temporary object, which will be dropped afterwards. This is the origin on the errors.

You can fix it, when you remove all `[..]` from the code.

```
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Node<T: 'static> {
    pub name: T,
    pub children: &'static [Node<T>],
}
pub fn return_root() -> Node<&'static str> {
    return Node {
        name: "root",
        children: &[Node {
            name: "uk",
            children: &[
                Node {
                    name: "ac",
                    children: &[],
                },
                Node {
                    name: "co",
                    children: &[
                        Node {
                            name: "blogspot",
                            children: &[],
                        },
                        Node {
                            name: "no-ip",
                            children: &[],
                        },
                    ],
                },
                Node {
                    name: "gov",
                    children: &[Node {
                        name: "service",
                        children: &[],
                    }],
                },
                Node {
                    name: "ltd",
                    children: &[],
                },
                Node {
                    name: "me",
                    children: &[],
                },
                Node {
                    name: "net",
                    children: &[],
                },
                Node {
                    name: "nhs",
                    children: &[],
                },
                Node {
                    name: "org",
                    children: &[],
                },
                Node {
                    name: "plc",
                    children: &[],
                },
                Node {
                    name: "police",
                    children: &[],
                },
                Node {
                    name: "sch",
                    children: &[Node {
                        name: "*",
                        children: &[],
                    }],
                },
            ],
        }],
    };
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=963995dc2b5c4e84b100b720394ff2c1&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015)

The `[..]` is not needed, because it only creates a slice from the other slice, which results in the same slice.